# How to display $date in node.tpl.php using a preprocess function in template.php

Tags: 7, theming

I want to check if the node is not a static page, and display `$date` in "node.tpl.php" within this `<div>`:

```
<div id="postDateArea"></div>
```

I currently have this in my node.tpl.php file:

```
<div id="postDateArea"><?php print $date; ?></div>
```

I currently have this in my template.php file:

```
function thebridge_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if($vars['type'] != 'static_page') {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function thebridge_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if($vars['type'] != 'static_page') {
    $vars['date'] = date('Y-m-d');
  }
}
```

You might want to change the parameters of date(). More information in the [Drupal documentation](http://drupal.org/node/223430).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [format_date](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/format_date) function:

```
function thebridge_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['date'] = format_date($vars['node']->created);
}
```

There are more parameters to `format_date`, most important the 'custom' format which allows for a custom PHP `date()` [format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
function thebridge_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['date'] = format_date($vars['node']->created, 'custom', 'F j');
}
```